# How do you backup a database within SQL Server 2005 from the command line?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2005

I need to create a scheduled task that will backup a database within a SQL Server 2005 instance.

Is there a command line argument that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
OSQL -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE database_name TO DISK = 'path and filename'"
```

As in:

```
OSQL -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE master TO DISK = 'C:\master.bak'"
```

Be sure you're running that as a user who has rights to backup that database (or, alternatively, use the "-U" and "-P" arguments to supply a username/password on the command line... not a good idea, thought.)

Comment: Also assumes the default instance other wise you have to add the server as well.

Comment: dont forget WITH INIT to overwrite the master.bak file, otherwise you'll end up with a massive .bak file with full backups appended to it

Answer (score 7):

Actually better here is to use SQLCMD instead of OSQL. OSQL is considered deprecated as of SQL Server 2005, though it's still around in SQL Server 2008.